# MongoDB SSL/TLS CA not trusted by anyone

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I used Let's Encrypt to setup Mongo with encryption. However, unless I provide the `--CAFile` and `--PEMKeyFile` arguments I am unable to connect to the DB. I just get a cryptic error.

```
[timestamp] DBClientCursor::init call() failed
[timestamp] Error: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: example.com:27017 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 } at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

That error, according to [this issue on mongodb.org](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12966) is caused by SSL configuration.

I used Let's Encrypt, whose Root CA is the ISRG Root X1. I verified that I have the proper `.pem` file by checking the Let's Encrypt page. Based on that Jira error/cryptic output and the fact that unless I provide the CA and PemKey arguments to the mongo shell I can't access the server I'm pretty sure that no one is trusting the SSL certs I'm using.

The exact procedure I used to get the certs is [here](https://gist.github.com/leommoore/1e773a7d230ca4bbe1c2). The only difference is that I created the `ca.pem` file then concatenated the `chain.pem` file into it. If I did it the other way, as the tutorial describes, it always failed the OpenSSL verification command.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of trying I figured it out:

By default, MongoDB doesn't use one-way SSL like most web servers do. Rather, it requires SSL certs from both the client and the server.

There is a flag, `--allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates`, that will bypass this.